# Use a variable in a jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, variables, selector

All,
I have a variable like this:

```
var get_form_id = formid.split('_');
var vendor_id = get_form_id[1];
```

I would like to use this in a selector then because some of my divs are variable. So for example, I'd like to fade in a div like this:

```
$("#star_loader").fadeIn(function()
```

but I want to use my variable. I tried to do something like:

```
$("#star_loader"+vendor_id).fadeIn(function()
```

That didn't work though. How can I use this correctly? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Can you post your HTML? There might be a better way of doing this using jQuery selectors like `.siblings()` or `.parent()` etc.

Comment: did you alert the string you build as selector? do it and write variable names in camelcase

Comment: I believe your error lies elsewhere, see http://jsfiddle.net/Ward/wpUJ4/

Comment: what do you get as `vendor_id`? do you have an element in the DOM at the time you are doing `$("#star_loader"+vendor_id).fadeIn(function()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work without problems. [See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wD6BE/).

Answer (score 0):

You are using it correctly assuming that `"#star_loader"+vendor_id` resolves to a valid element ID. Are you missing an underscore? Try using `console.log("#star_loader"+vendor_id)` either in the javascript console of your web browser or directly via the script. When all else fails, there's always `alert("#star_loader"+vendor_id)`.